# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': CordovaError: Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova

Tags: angular, xcode, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to perform `phone authentication` using `firebase` in my app(ionic V-4).After creating the app, I just added the `android/ios` platforms  using the below commands:

```
 ionic cordova platform add android
 ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Then tried to install firebase plugin like this:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
```

It is throwing this error:

[image]

I am developing the app in `windows`.

Comment: Did Peter's answer help? Or you solved it some other way?

Answer (score 21):

You are using cordova 9, and in that version [`requireCordovaModule`](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/03/22/cordova-cli-release-9.0.0.html) was deprecated for non cordova modules and thats why you get the following error.

You need to navigate to the following js file in your environment:

https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/blob/master/scripts/ios/helper.js#L33

and change:

```
var xcode = context.requireCordovaModule("xcode");
```

into this ( since [xcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xcode) is an npm package):

```
var xcode = require("xcode");
```

Comment: just to add, there's one one more on line 88

Answer (score 4):

Actually, your are working on `Windows` and you added an iOS platform.
This is not working.

Remove the iOS platform :

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
```

Then try to install firebase by doing the command below :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
npm install @ionic-native/firebase
```

Good luck !

Comment: I am using mac operating system but facing same issue.

Comment: same, using mac.

Answer (score 3):

Remove iOS platform, it requires a MacOS environment.

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you add plugin it try to install for iOS as well and you are trying it in window pc and xcode not installed on windows.

If you remove ios plaform and try for only android then it will work.